# Office 365 - Move a maillbox to a different user

Tags: email, office365, azure-active-directory

I am trying to move a mailbox from 1 user to another in Office 365.
We have Dirsync set up to keep everything synchronised.
The reason for this is that we occasionally get corrupt AD accounts so we have to set up a new account and copy over the data (this doesn't happen a lot, but it does happen).
 
I have checked through all the online help from Microsoft and other sources but just can't find a way that works.
I have tried deleting the mailbox, then restoring it:
 
One guide said to use the GUID's to transfer the account, but a deleted account doesn't have a GUID.
Another guide says to use Restore-MsolUser - but you can't specify a new AD account.

So in a nutshell all I want to achieve is this:
Local AD user "A" has the email "A@xyz.com" needs to change to
Local AD user "B" has the email "A@xyz.com"

At the moment we have to keep both the old and the new AD accounts active to maintain the email, but if the user changes their password on the new account it obviously doesn't sync with their email account as it's on their old AD account.

I have been trawling through internet guides for weeks but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
John